# SQL attribution

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have a query to calculate attribution and I want the results inserted into a column. New to this hence the basic nature of my query!

There are 2 tables `testvisits` and `testsales`. I want to find the even-share for each visit, and put the results in the column `revenue_modelA` in the `testvisits` table.

Here's what I have so far....

```
select
    s.saleID,
    count(v.visitID) as visits,
    s.revenue,
    (select s.revenue/count(DISTINCT v.visitID) as visits) as "Even-Share" 
from 
    testvisits v
join 
    testsales s on v.saleid = s.saleid
where 
    v.saleid = s.saleid
group by 
    s.saleID, s.revenue
order by 
    s.saleID

insert into testvisits (revenue_modelA)
values ('select s.revenue/count(DISTINCT v.visitID)
         from testvisits v
         join testsales s on v.saleid = s.saleid
         where v.saleid = s.saleid')
```

Any info you need please ask, and thanks for your help.

Tim

Comment: What database are you use? set tag please

Answer (score 0):

You should use ***insert select*** construction for Oracle database query will look:

```
insert into testvisits(revenue_modela)
    (
        select s.revenue / count(distinct v.visitid)
        from testvisits v
        join testsales s
        on v.saleid = s.saleid
        where v.saleid = s.saleid
    );
```

look also [syntax for oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/insert-select.html)

### How work insert

For example your table ***testvisits*** have follow ***structure/columns:

> - saleID (not null)
> - revenue_modela (can be null)
> - description (can be null)

when you do insert, even if you have chosen one column ***revenue_modela***:

`insert into testvisits (revenue_modela) values ('some value');`

It will still attempt to insert values into all columns and run the following query:

`insert into testvisits (saleID, revenue_modela, desctiption) values (null, 'some value', null);`

So will attempt to insert ***null*** value to ***saleID*** column. And you catch exeption.

Comment: Thanks HAYMbI4! its Microsoft sql and I have a new error now after adding group by   insert into testvisits(revenue_modela)
    (
        select s.revenue / count(distinct v.visitid)
        from testvisits v
        join testsales s
        on v.saleid = s.saleid
        where v.saleid = s.saleid
  group by s.revenue
    );

Comment: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'saleID', table 'sqlTest.dbo.testvisits'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @TimHawkins, I think in your table ***testvisits*** you have ***saleID*** field, that have ***not null constraint***. And when you do insert, you try set null value in this field.

Comment: I don't understand why its trying to insert into saleid though. I just want the insert in revenue_modela!

Comment: @TimHawkins, I edit my answer, look it. For more information read doc for insert in Microsoft SQL

Comment: @TimHawkins, use ***update*** if you want change some data in table row, ***update*** doesn't create new row. If you want create new row you need use ***insert***

Comment: @TimHawkins, if my answer are useful for you please set vote up and klick accept answer